# installing libssl-dev in fedora7

Tags: fedora

I know, I'm using an old fedora version so please don't comment on that. I just want to know if anybody could help install libssl-dev in fedora7. Per my search, it seems that libssl-dev has no rpm for fedora 7 or any fedora version.

Can someone give me hints as to how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

libssl-dev is the Debian name for the OpenSSL development libraries.

On the RHEL side, it's called openssl-devel.